# git is getting distracted by git repos in subdirectories

Tags: git

When I'm doing research, I often clone associated repos into subdirectories of the main project. The main project has the main repo in its root directory, which I use to make commits. After migrating to a new Mac I am having trouble getting the main git repo to work in my project.

When I execute `git remote -v` I see the correct remote.

```
origin  https://github.com/my_user_id/this_project.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/my_user_id/this_project.git (push)
```

When I execute `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` I see the correct local.

```
~/my_user_id/Documents/my_projects/this_project
```

But when I execute `git status` I get the message:

```
fatal: '~/my_user_id/Documents/my_projects/this_project/other_subproject/.git' not recognized as a git repository
```

Comment: you should either add the directory of the subrepo to the `.gitignore` list or explicitly track it as a `submodule`

Comment: also, this error does not happen normally. How did you create your repository? Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I believe the source of this error is that I migrated folders over to a new Mac via Google Drive. When I tried to start using the git repos in these migrated folders I saw the above issues (and others).

Comment: Here is the issue. You should not use google drive to sync git directories. The format of the `.git` repository directory is different between various operating systems. Sync your repository using github or some other git+http/git+ssh service (using `git clone`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've used a cloud syncing service to move data between computers.  While the format of a Git repository is stable between OSes, it isn't safe to use a cloud syncing service like Google Drive to copy data because of the way it works.

Most cloud syncing services copy files one at a time across machines in a relatively arbitrary order, and if two versions of the same file exist (such as two files representing the same branch with different contents), they may arbitrarily choose one and either ignore the other or create a second file along side.  Git relies on objects being written into the repository in a specific order (first blobs, then trees referring to blobs and other trees, then commits referring to trees) and it also relies on the fact that a reference isn't updated unless the commit is present and valid.

Cloud syncing service preserve none of these invariants and very frequently corrupt repositories, so they should never be used for copying repositories and you should never store your repositories in a directory managed by a cloud syncing service.

If you need to transfer files, you can either do so by pushing to a remote, either HTTPS or SSH, or you can use `rsync` with SSH to transfer files to a new machine.  If you use `rsync`, the repository must be completely quiescent; that is, there must be no Git processes, including `git gc` or Git processes spawned by your editor, in use on the repository while it's being synced.  Note that if the destination directory exists when using `rsync`, the data there will be destroyed.